# How to COUNT DISTINCT record SQL?

Tags: sql, informix

I have a script to count distinct id for registration once per year

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id),
MONTH(reg_date), YEAR(reg_date)
FROM reg_tbl
WHERE YEAR(reg_date) IN (2013, 2014, 2015)
```

I want to have the data count each `id` only once per year even if it is returned more than once. I would also like the id to be counted in the maximum month it was registered. That is, if the `id` is registered in January, February and March of a specific year I would like it to be counted once but within the month of the latest registration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to aggregate the data by year to get the latest value for each id in the year.  Then, you can do the count by month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(reg_date), YEAR(reg_date)
FROM (SELECT id, YEAR(reg_date) as yyyy, MAX(reg_date) as reg_date
      FROM reg_tbl rt
      GROUP BY id, YEAR(reg_date)
     ) rty
WHERE yyyy IN (2013, 2014, 2015)
GROUP BY MONTH(reg_date), YEAR(reg_date);
```

Note:  You no longer need `count(distinct)` in the outer query, because the subquery only returns one row per id per year.

Comment: Thanks for you speedy response. Can you say if it is possible for me to just put the `MAX(MONTH(reg_date))` and get the same result without the sub query.

Comment: @Kefash: No, you need the subquery (derived table). But you can get it a bit faster and more readable in my opinion, by not selecting `MAX(reg_date) as reg_date` but `MAX(MONTH(reg_date)) as reg_month` instead and using this and by moving the WHERE clause to the subquery (`WHERE YEAR(reg_date) IN (2013, 2014, 2015)`.

Comment: Even though Gordon Linoff answer did work I would just like to point out that by just using `MAX(MONTH(reg_date))` I did get the same result.

Comment: I am using Informix Database and I am getting a syntax error at the `id` field in the sub query. can you say why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a subquery

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
     id,
     MONTH(reg_date), 
     YEAR(reg_date)
   FROM 
     reg_tbl
   WHERE 
     YEAR(reg_date) IN (2013, 2014, 2015)) Data
```

Hope this helps

Comment: partially, but I wanted it to return more than just the count of the record but also the month and year field.